# how to add table name as one of the parameters of the hibernate template query

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

Obviously, the hibernate template query injects the string parameter "tableName" into the query with quotes. Which will cause SQL grammar syntax errors.

How to add the table name as one of the query params?

For example, the following code will not work because of the table name:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT ID FROM :tableName");
query.setFlushMode(FlushMode.MANUAL);
query.setReadOnly(true);
query.setParameter("tableName", "STUDENT");
List<Object[]> list = query.list();
```

Answer (score 5):

Table names cannot be parametrized in queries.

What you actually want to achieve is to build a `String` which will be used to construct the query:

```
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(getIdsQuery("STUDENT"));
...
private String getIdsQuery(String tableName) {
   return "SELECT ID FROM " + tableName;
}
```

The lack of the ability to parametrize table names has nothing to do with Hibernate - the databases don't support it. And it would make no sense to support it.

The bind variables exist primarily for performance reasons. The point is that you send a query to the database (via jdbc driver) with the placeholders for variables that will change between the invocations of *the same* query:

```
select id from STUDENT where name = ?
```

The database will parse this query, calculate the cost for it, make an execution plan and cache it. The subsequent invocations of the query will be much faster, because all of these steps are skipped and the [cached execution plan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35871/preparedstatement-caching-size-on-oracle-and-sql-server) is used.

How could the database cache the statement and the execution plan if the table name is unknown (parametrized)? It would not know the cost and optimal path to fetch the data if it does not know where to fetch the data from.

Also, the database would not be able to completely validate the query when parsing it if it does not know whether the referenced columns actually exist in the table (which would be unknown at statement parse time if the table names were parametrized).

Comment: This is what I am doing, but I still don't understand why doesn't hibernate support parameterizing table names. :)

Comment: This answer can lead to sql injection, a very easy to manipulate security hole.  That is also why parameters cannot be used for table names.

Answer (score 0):

Your HQL query should look like this :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Conversation as c where c.userConversation.id=:senderid and c.user1Conversation.id=:receiverid");
```

Here Conversation is the model class name, 'c' is the alias, and userConversation is the many-to-one mapping I have. So answering your question, you can put table name in the above manner. Please dont forget to set query parameters.

Also, you dont need to set the FlushMode to manual, as you are just reading the list, you dont even need to call session.flush after that. Secondly, why are you setting hard-coded values for query.setParameter???

*Update*

I just read your post. Your SQL query should look like this :

```
select id,username from Conversation where id=1000;
```

Above is just an example, but Conversation is still the table name. Also, you have tagged your post as Hibernate, thats why I wrote a HQL query, it is much more easier to do stuff in HQL is what I have experienced.

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = session.createQuery(String.format("select id from %s", "Student"));
```

it's same thing as first answer (but using some Java help): You need to construct a String to pass as query